# Using + operator in XML DTD

Tags: xml, dtd, xml-validation

I have query regarding specifying sub-parts of an element while defining a DTD for XML. I want to have an element titled "Description", which may have any inter-leaved sequence of a BookRef and PCDATA. I'm using following statement in my XML DTD.

```
<!ELEMENT Description (#PCDATA|Courseref)* >
```

However, I want to enforce a more strict constraint than *. I want to use +, which should mandate the having of at least one PCDATA or Courseref. However, when I use + instead of *, I get a parse error using xmllint.

I'm new to DTD and I want to know, if it is illegal as per XML DTD Specs to specify a + operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the XML spec requires that content models of the form

```
(#PCDATA | foo | bar | baz)*
```

list `#PCDATA` first and use `*` not `+` (or anything else) as the occurrence indicator (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Mixed).

A lot of design considerations played into this, most of them now of purely historical importance.  One, however, may be worth noticing:  if `+` were allowed and you did write

```
<!ELEMENT Description (#PCDATA|Courseref)+ >
```

the element declaration would define precisely the same set of valid element instances as the form using `*`:  the token `#PCDATA` matches zero or more characters of parsed character data, so an element instance like `<Description/>` would be valid against either form of the element declaration (the zero-length string matches the content-model token `#PCDATA` once, so the requirement that a `+`-marked choice be satisfied at least once would be met).

You might convey your intent here by making Description contain

```
(p+ | Courseref)
```

and saying in the documentation that empty `p` (paragraph) elements are frowned upon.  But DTDs do not provide a way of requiring that there be any minimum length content for a `#PCDATA` string.  That's one reason some people prefer to use XSD, or Schematron, or Relax NG.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a [mixed content model](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content) (both #PCDATA and elements (`Courseref`)), you have to use the `*` occurrence indicator.

If you didn't have #PCDATA in the model, you could use `+`.

The key piece of info from [mixed content model section](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content) of the spec:

> ...the types of the child elements may be constrained, but not their
>   order or their number of occurrences